# Nested JSON parsing in android using url

Tags: android, json

I am new to JSON parsing and I am stuck in this nested JSON parsing.Here is the attached JSON data for one city only which I get from the url :

```
{
"CityCode": 142,
"CityName": "Yavatmal",
"State": {
"StateCode": 21,
"StateName": "Maharashtra",
"CountryCode": 1,
"Country": {
  "CountryCode": 1,
  "CountryName": "India",
  "IsdCode": "+91"
}
},
"Country": {
"CountryCode": 1,
"CountryName": "India",
"IsdCode": "+91"
},
"GPlaceId": "ChIJ3U60i8zo0zsR4L7sQeqtd0g",
"Latitude": 20.388794,
"Longitude": 78.120407,
"ActiveStatus": 1
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to parse this type of JSON data in such a way that I can display each key in a textView.

Comment: What have you done so far? I recommend to use some library, e.g. [GSON](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

the scope sorrounded by "{" "}" are called json object. You can extract like          `

```
String jsonData = ""//received json string    
jsonObject obj = new JSONSObject(jsonData);`
obj.getString("CityCode");
obj.getJSONObject("state");
```

if the key hold the single value , then you can get that in string. If the key itself hold another jsonobject , extract that into separate jsonobject and repeat.

Comment: Can I put the URL in the String jsonData ?

Comment: for retrieve the value ?.. you cant. String jsondata is the received response from the Async Call.